# How to count group by condition in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My input dataframe name 'df'

[image]

I want to create a new dataframe name 'df1' group by 'date' in df, which include 2 fields: 'date' and 'sponsorRate' with calculation formula as below

date = df.date
sponsorRate = count(sponsored) on check column / count total on check column

My desired output

[image]

Tks for all helps

Comment: I'am sorry I fixed correct dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `check` and aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = df['check'].eq('sponsored').groupby('date').mean().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df['check'].eq('sponsored').groupby(level=0).mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Many tks Jez! This worked for me.